# How to mock child component in Angular 10 unit test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a problem when I try to mock a child component of the component that I am trying to test. Bellow, I will provide the dependencies of the project as well as what I am trying to achieve.

dependencies:

> ```
> "@angular/animations": "^10.2.3",
> "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
> "@angular/common": "^10.2.3",
> "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.3",
> "@angular/core": "^10.2.3",
> "@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
> "@angular/forms": "^10.2.3",
> "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
> "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^10.2.7",
> "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.3",
> "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.3",
> "@angular/router": "^10.2.3",
> "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
> "@ngrx/effects": "^10.1.2",
> "@ngrx/store": "^10.1.2",
> "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
> "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
>  ...
> ```

devDependencies:

> ```
> "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.0",
> "@angular/cli": "^10.2.0",
> "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.3",
> "@angular/language-service": "^10.2.3",
> "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
> "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.3",
> "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
> "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
> "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
> "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
> "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
> "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
> "karma": "~5.0.0",
> "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
> "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
> "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
> "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
> "protractor": "~7.0.0",
> "ts-node": "~8.6.2",
> "tslint": "~6.1.0",
> "typescript": "~4.0.5" 
> ...
> ```

And this is a summary of the parent and child components and what I am trying to achieve.

**parent.component.html**

```html
<div id="employee-data" class="employee-data">
    <ng-container *ngIf="state?.render">
        <j-table></j-table>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

In the parent component, I have this child component `j-table` which is quite complex, and should be tested with its own logic.

I want to test if the child component `j-table` will be rendered if the `*ngIf="state?.render"` condition is true.

**parent.component.spec.ts**

```js
it('should render j-table if state.render is set to true', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.componentInstance.state.render = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const table = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(JTableStubComponent));
    expect(table).toBeTruthy();
}))
```

In order to mock the child component `j-table`, I have defined this stub:

```js
@Component({ selector: 'j-table', template: '' })
class JTableStubComponent implements Partial<JTableComponent> {}
```

However, this causes the test to fail with the error: `Error: Multiple components match node with tagname j-table`.

According to the Angular unit test official documentation, and some of the answers regarding the same problem on the web, this should not be a problem. I am suspecting the Angular version that I am using, or I might be making some minor mistake that I cannot see.

I can provide more code or other resources if necessary.

**Edit 1:**

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [EmployeesComponent, JTableStubComponent],
    imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: EmployeesService,
            useValue: mockEmployeeService
        }
    ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
});
```

Comment: Even by using `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` the tests fail.

Comment: With `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` you don't need any declarations for the `j-table` tag - your problem is you somehow have *two*.

Comment: By using `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` Angular attempts to render the original component and the test fails due to missing `@Input()` values. e.g: `cannot read property of undefined`

Comment: Actually `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` or `CUSTOM_COMPONENTS_SCHEMA` is the way to go when mocking your components. Could you please share a bit more information or even better create a stackblitz so it is possible to understand where the two j-table components were declard and why you get `cannot read property of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-mocks](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/guides/component) in order to simplify boilerplate.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  // Tell what to test and where to mock dependencies.
  return MockBuilder(EmployeesComponent, EmployeesModule);
});

it('renders', () => {
  // enjoy
  const fixture = MockRender(EmployeesComponent);
});
```